# Syntax error when querying in BigQuery, only difference is "lookup" as an alias in query

Tags: google-bigquery

The following query does not work, although it seems a valid syntax.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM

(
SELECT 
  fullvisitorid
FROM [93207306.ga_sessions_20150823]
) as lookup

LIMIT 1000
```

However the following query works, when I changed `lookup` to something else.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM

(
SELECT 
  fullvisitorid
FROM [93207306.ga_sessions_20150823]
) as lookuptable

LIMIT 1000
```

Is there any explanation of this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because LOOKUP is reserved keyword in BigQuery for future use, but it is not used anywhere right now. Until BigQuery fixes it, the workaround is to quote it with square braces just like other keywords, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
  fullvisitorid
FROM [93207306.ga_sessions_20150823]
) as [lookup]
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Would it be possible to publish a list of those reserved words?